# compressed video file not play in VideoView from WebServer

Tags: android, android-studio, video-streaming, android-videoview

i'm developing application which record the video and save to web server, and since recorded video have too much size i use some compression technique [GiraffeCompressor](https://github.com/tcking/GiraffeCompressor) and [SiliCompressor](https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor) in order to reduce size of original video.

after applying compression technique video size r educes and i also play that compressed video file into my [VideoView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView)

till here everything is working perfectly

when i upload compressed video file to server and try to play video from url in [VideoView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView), it's not playing.

here is my source code of playing video from url in [VideoView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView).
and my [VideoView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView) code work perfectly for playing another video (from url) but it not play my compressed video file.

video play from my LocalHost Server (work perfectly ) but not able to play video from Live Hosted Server.

is there anything wrong with my code ? please help me.

```
        VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vv);
        vv.setZOrderOnTop(true);

        try {
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(vv);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(_video_link);
            vv.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            vv.setVideoURI(uri);
            vv.seekTo(1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        vv.requestFocus();
        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.setLooping(true);
                vv.start();

            }
        });
        vv.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                vv.resume();
            }
        });
```

here is my logcat

```
   05-24 10:04:04.150 14581-14581/? D/MediaPlayerNative: getMetadata
05-24 10:04:04.151 14581-14581/? I/MediaPlayer: constructor
05-24 10:04:04.156 14581-14581/? I/MediaPlayer: start
05-24 10:04:04.157 14581-14581/? I/MediaPlayer: start
05-24 10:04:04.207 14581-14717/? W/MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (804, -2147479551)
05-24 10:04:04.211 14581-14717/? W/MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (804, -38)
05-24 10:04:04.229 14581-14717/? W/MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (3, 0)
05-24 10:04:04.267 14581-14581/? I/MediaPlayer: constructor
05-24 10:04:04.270 14581-14581/? I/MediaPlayer: setDataSource:http://www.selfilife.com/App/media/priteshvishwakarma/post_video/VIDEO_20180522_122801.mp4
05-24 10:04:04.271 14581-14581/? W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://www.selfilife.com/App/media/priteshvishwakarma/post_video/VIDEO_20180522_122801.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://www.selfilife.com/App/media/priteshvishwakarma/post_video/VIDEO_20180522_122801.mp4
05-24 10:04:04.271 14581-14581/? I/MediaPlayer: setDataSource:http://www.selfilife.com/App/media/priteshvishwakarma/post_video/VIDEO_20180522_122801.mp4
```

Comment: Could you please also add logs (when you try to play compressed video). Also please provide compressed and uncompressed file meta info (encoding, container etc). You could use https://www.get-metadata.com/ for this.

Comment: original file meta data  = https://www.get-metadata.com/result/28cda5a1-507f-4be4-a25c-a4ecaf5cbeab

compressed file meta data  = https://www.get-metadata.com/result/ac2acf3f-ae7f-4408-b6ca-b2e822013e40

Comment: @MaxUkhanov here is my meta data information about my media file i.e. original file and compressed file

Comment: @MaxUkhanov i added log also , please go through it

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try to use
   `vv.setVideoPath(testVideoURL);` instead of `vv.setVideoURI(uri);` Possible this could hepls.
2. I'm just guessing, but in case of using self-signed https certificate on the backend similar issue could appear. Please attach your logs if possible.

   UPD. Looks like you already found that the issue is inside of the `SiliCompressor` library https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor/issues/36

Comment: yes this is the same problem which im facing right now

Comment: i tried your first option , it dosn't make any changes

Comment: i read [this](https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor/issues/36)  issue on git